# Bitbucket Pipeline not firing when yaml changed

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using Bitbucket Pipeline.  When I make changes to the yaml file, the Pipeline won't fire.  I'll comment out a line and it stops firing.  I uncomment it back out and it fires again.  Trivial changes and it will/won't fire.  What gives?  I've checked it with the yaml checker that Bitbucket suggests and the yaml is valid

Answer (score 2):

I've had strange problems with indentation where it passes a YAML lint check but fails when I try it in bitbucket. My advice is to copy one of the examples from [their site](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-pipelines-beta-792496469.html#BitbucketPipelines(beta)-php_example) and modify it to meet your needs, keeping the same indentation as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are indenting with spaces, not tabs.

Also, watch the pipeline output closely whilst it is building and failing. I've had occasions where an error in my YAML was reported for just a few seconds before being removed from the screen.